# How to add collider to prefab with C# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I downloaded the Unity MegaCity and I want to make it into a game. But I need to add a collider to the cars. I added one to the prefab itself, but it doesn't work in-game so I need to use the code to add one. How do I do that? The code is here:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Entities;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Collections;

namespace Traffic.Simulation
{
public class TrafficSettings : MonoBehaviour, IConvertGameObjectToEntity, IDeclareReferencedPrefabs
{
public float pathSegments=100;
public float globalSpeedFactor = 1.0f;
public int maxCars = 2000;
public Collider PrefabCollider;

public float[] speedMultipliers;

public List<GameObject> vehiclePrefabs;



public void DeclareReferencedPrefabs(List<GameObject> gameObjects)
{
for (int i = 0; i < vehiclePrefabs.Count; i++)
{
gameObjects.Add(vehiclePrefabs[i]);
}
}

public void Convert(Entity entity, EntityManager dstManager, GameObjectConversionSystem conversionSystem)
{
for (int j = 0; j < vehiclePrefabs.Count; j++)
{
// A primary entity needs to be called before additional entities can be used
Entity vehiclePrefab = conversionSystem.CreateAdditionalEntity(this);
var prefabData = new VehiclePrefabData
{
VehiclePrefab = conversionSystem.GetPrimaryEntity(vehiclePrefabs[j]),
VehicleSpeed = j < speedMultipliers.Length ? speedMultipliers[j] : 3.0f
};
dstManager.AddComponentData(vehiclePrefab, prefabData);
}
var trafficSettings = new TrafficSettingsData
{
GlobalSpeedFactor = globalSpeedFactor,
PathSegments = pathSegments,
MaxCars = maxCars
};

dstManager.AddComponentData(entity, trafficSettings);
}
}
}
```

Is there a function like gameobjects.SetCollider or somethiing?

Comment: define "doesnt work"

Comment: I added a capsule collider to the car. I expected it to spawn with the cloned prefabs, but the collider does not show up in game.

Comment: well you're converting them to entities, so they do show up different.  Thats a "joy" of ecs, do they have physicscolliders on?

Comment: Did you apply the changes (in this case: adding the collider) to the prefab?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddComponent` to add a component (in this case a collider).

This line of code will add a component (in my case a sphere collider). This can be used for **any type of component.**

```
SphereCollider collider = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(SphereCollider)) as SphereCollider;
```

The name for the Sphere Collider is `collider` as specified before

```
gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(SphereCollider)) as SphereCollider;
```

Docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html

Comment: Did this work? If it did, please accept my answer so I can know that it worked - and it also help the community! Win-win. If it does not work, tell me by commenting so that I can help you further.